# 415 Unsupported Media Type in ionic 2 - Web-service POST?

Tags: web-services, http, post, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to make a POST request at the login of my application in Ionic 2.

```
var link = 'https://domain.name/login' + '?appname=' + "name";
var data = JSON.stringify({username: "0000000", password: "12345678"});
var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.http.post(link, data, {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(data => {
        var alert = Alert.create({
            title: "Data String",
            subTitle: data.json().data,
            buttons: ["close"]
        });
        this.nav.present(alert);
    }, error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
});
```

But its giving below error. Although I have set the content type its giving below error.

```
415 Unsupported Media Type 
{"Message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to import the Headers class. In this case the headers you defined by your own aren't send in the request...

```
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
```

Could you check what you have for this request in the Network tab of developer tools? Do you have the Content-Type header?

Answer (score 2):

use  this.http.setDataSerializer('json'); before post

Comment: Could you provide your working code to make your answer more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use **set** instead of *append* as it is immutable. Something like this-

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```